# Calculate Average of JSON Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach, average

I am trying to calculate the average of JSON values, I tried to add them to an array but not able to. Can someone please help?

My code:

```
Object.values(data).forEach(d => {
  var yo = d.values;
  console.log(yo);
});
```

My results:

```
9892308
9894522
3298714
3300055
```

I need to calculate the average of these values. How do I do that?

Code to push values in an array:

```
Object.values(data).forEach(d => {
  var theArray = [];
  var yo = d.values;
  theArray = theArray.push(yo);
  console.log(theArray);
});
```

Result:

```
  1
```

I am not able to push the values for me to calculate the array.

Comment: *I tried to add them to an array but not able to*  show us what you tried

Comment: Otherwise, conceptually, you'd set a variable to 0 before the forEach, add the values to it in the forEach, and after the forEach divide by the number of values.

Comment: You would add them all together & then divide them by the number of items. That's how you calculate the average of a set.

Comment: The math is pretty basic. How many `Object.values()` are there? What's the total? How do you add numbers in javscript?

Comment: Also, slight smell.  Your model variable is called "values", but it appears to only have a single value in it.

Comment: @Taplar Ive added the array push

Comment: @Taplar I showed in the results that it has 4 values

Comment: @newbierp that's four different console logs.  Each logging a single value originating from a variable of "values" on the `d`.  That's a smell

Comment: The issue with your snippet is `var theArray = [];` is creating a new array every iteration.  Only create it once before the loop

Comment: @Taplar, makes sense! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the data by taking the nth (length) of the value and add it to the average in a single loop.

```js
var data = { a: { values: 9892308 }, b: { values: 9894522 }, c: { values: 3298714 }, d: { values: 3300055 } },
    average = Object
        .values(data)
        .reduce((avg, { values }, _, { length }) => avg + values / length, 0);
        
console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you have your data structured, but an `Array.reduce` should get you the sum, and divide by the length for the average.

```js
const data = {
  a: {
    values: 9892308,
  },
  b: {
    values: 9894522,
  },
  c: {
    values: 3298714,
  },
  something_weird: {
    values: 3300055,
  }
}





const sum = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, current) => acc + current.values, 0);

const average = sum / Object.values(data).length;
console.log(average);
```